# CheckListBox для свойства коллекции в PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

У меня есть небольшой класс от UITypeEditor, необходим мне, для того, чтобы в PropertyGrid для свойства коллекции был выпадающий список с галочками.
Например, я создаю категорию продуктов (фрукты, овощи) в продуктовом списке и есть список всех продуктов, в котором мне нужно выбрать те, что относятся именно к этой категории. Т.е. я добавляю в пустой продуктовый список новую категорию "Фрукты", и для этой категории выбираю из глобального списка продуктов те, которые к ней относятся: "Яблоки", "Груши", "Бананы". Далее я хочу создать еще одну категорию, например "Овощи" и снова выбрать из глобального списка какие-то овощи. Проблема в том, что после создания последней категории, все остальные категории получают тот же набор продуктов, что и последняя.
вот код:

```
public class CheckedListBoxUiTypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private readonly CheckedListBox _checklisbox1 = new CheckedListBox();

    private IWindowsFormsEditorService _es;

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override bool IsDropDownResizable => true;

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        if (provider != null)
        {
            _es = provider.GetService(typeof (IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
        }

        if (_es != null)
        {
            LoadValues(value);
            _es.DropDownControl(_checklisbox1);
        }

        _result.Clear();

        foreach (string str in _checklisbox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            _result.Add(str);
        }
        return _result;
    }

    private readonly List<string> _defaultList = FormLas.ListAll;

    private readonly List<string> _result = new List<string>(); 

    private void LoadValues(object value)
    {
        Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
        foreach (string str in _defaultList)
        {
            table.Add(str, false);
        }
        _checklisbox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry dic in table)
        {
            _checklisbox1.Items.Add(dic.Key, (bool) dic.Value);
        }

        if (((List<string>) value).Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string str in (List<string>)value)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _checklisbox1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (str == _checklisbox1.Items[i])
                    {
                        _checklisbox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашла ошибку, проблема была в глобальных переменных (_defaultList, _result), инициализацию этих переменных необходимо поместить в тело методов. Тоже самое нужно сделать для объекта _checklisbox1.